# exists(A) and not exists(negA) vs custom aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

Many times, I have to select the customers that have made {criteria set A} of transactions and not any OTHER type of transactions. Sample data:

```
create table customer (name nvarchar(max))
insert customer values
('George'),
('Jack'),
('Leopold'),
('Averel')

create table trn (id int,customer nvarchar(max),product char(1))
insert trn values
(1,'George','A'),
(2,'George','B'),
(3,'Jack','B'),
(4,'Leopold','A')
```

Let's say we want to find all customers who bought product 'A' and not anything else (in this case, B).
The most typical way to do this includes joining the transaction table with itself:

```
select * from customer c
where exists(select 1 from trn p where p.customer=c.name and product='A')
and not exists(select 1 from trn n where n.customer=c.name and product='B')
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this. Keep in mind that the transaction table should typically be huge.

What about this alternative:

```
select * from customer c
where exists
(
    select 1
    from trn p
    where p.customer=c.name
    group by p.customer
    having max(case when product='B' then 2 when product='A' then 1 else 0 end)=1
)
```

Will the fact that the transaction table is used only once offset the aggregation calculation needed?

Comment: Have you done any benchmarking yet?  Note that you might have to tune each query separately to get it to its optimal point.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't. I guess the answer then is typicaly "it depends, check the execution plan out"?

Comment: You mentioned the scenario of purchasing 'A' and only 'A' - but have written it up with a product 'B' - as soon as there are hundreds / thousands of products then your alternative becomes unwieldy to write / maintain. (You would have to alter it to be more generic of `when product <> 'A'`.)  As mentioned test - but I would be surprised if the exists was not faster, it can quit sooner when it finds an existence, the group by / having can not.

Comment: [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: It's always possible for two queries that have equivalent result sets to result in identical plans, even from wildly different statements

Comment: @HoneyBadger This raises a philosophical point. When can I be sure I am not missing something obvious (or well-known in the community)? Example: If I asked how to make a query with "where year(datefield)=2018" faster, people would be fast to indicate that functions disable the use of indexes.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis You can always phrase year = 2018 as something like `datefield BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'`.  What you would do here in general is to first get some real data (SQL Server probably won't use any index at all for a table with 10 rows), then run both queries and look at the execution plans.  Next, try to tune each query.  What you would end up choosing might also depend on other tuning you have already done on these tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test performance on *your* data.  If you have an index on `trn(customer, product)`, then the `exists` would generally have very reasonable performance.

This is particularly true when you are using the `customers` table.

How well does the aggregation version compare?  First, the best aggregation would be:

```
select customer
from trn
where product in ('a', 'b')
group by customer
having min(product) = 'a' and max(product) = 'b';
```

If you have an index on `product` -- and there are lots of products (or few customers that have "a" and "b"), then this can be faster than the `not exists` version.

In general, I advocate using the `group by`, even though its performance is not always best on a couple of products.  Why?

- The use of the `having` clause is quite flexible for handling all different "set-within-set" conditions.
- Adding additional conditions doesn't have a large effect on performance.
- If you are not using a customer table but instead doing something like `(select distinct customer from trn)`, then the `exists`/`not exists` version is likely to be more expensive.

That said, I advocate using `group by` and `having` because it is more flexible.  That means that under the right circumstances, other solutions should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following statement. It **may be** faster than your statements under certain circumstances, since it will always determine first the customers with product A transactions and then looks only for these customers if there are transactions for other products. If there is really a benefit at all depends on the data and indexes of your real tables, so you have to try.

```
WITH customerA AS (SELECT DISTINCT customer FROM trn WHERE product = 'A')
SELECT DISTINCT customer.*
FROM customerA JOIN customer ON customerA.customer = customer.name
WHERE not exists(select 1 from trn n where n.customer = customerA.customer and
product <> 'A')
```